# WPF Not displaying what is seen on screen when compiled

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, alignment

I'm new to WPF and am used to winforms. I don't understand why the compiled output is not the same as in the design view. I find this to be bit annoying and misleading.

When adding elements, I snapped them to the red border and the results are not consistent with what I see in the compiled window. In winforms, I'm used to using table layouts, panels, and docking and aligning items. Is there a proper way of doing this in WPF to get consistent results?

[image: Designer View]

The XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="300" Margin="10,10,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="497"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image: The output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WPF most containers don't have the notion of children position. Instead, most controls use properties such as `Margin`, `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` to define their layout. Furthermore, specific containers offer different functions. If you want docking, you can use a `DockPanel`. If you want stacked elements, you can use a `StackPanel` and so on. I suggest you to look up a few tutorials online, it's plenty of resources.

In your case, if you want your control to completely fill its container, remove the `Margin`, `VerticalAlignment`, `HorizontalAlignment`, `Width` and `Height` attributes from its XAML code.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to learn about these differences. One thing I noticed is setting the SizeToContent to WidthAndHeight makes the window snap to the item which prevents extra empty space.

Comment: Once you get used to it, you'll find that it's much more intuitive and powerful the way WPF/SL does it. Positioning things by hand with anchors and left/top etc becomes just a memory. Relative layout also ensures your app scales nicely when you resize the screen or use it on a device with a different resolution